# Sample standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, integers

Give a set of 3 integers between 1 and 9 that would give a) the smallest value and b) the largest value of s (sample standard deviation) and find the value of s: i)if repeats are allowed and ii)if no repeats are allowed?

Is there an approach to this question or is it done by trial or error?
Thanks

Comment: If all three integers are the same value then the standard deviation will be zero. Since standard deviation is nonnegative this would have to be the smallest value.

Comment: Hint: if repeats are allowed, there's a way to choose such that there is no variance...

Comment: @Tucker, are you saying the standard deviation is allowed to  be zero?

Comment: @baudolino, What way can you choose such that there is no variance, I don't understand...

Comment: If repeats are allowed then you could get $4,4,4$, and then the standard deviation would be $0$.  If repeats are not allowed then to make the standard deviation small you have to make the three numbers as close to each other as possible, just as you do when repetition is allowed.  If you get $1,2,3$ then the standard deviation is the same as if you get $7,8,9$ (if that is not clear to you, then think about it, since you don't understand standard deviations if you don't understand that).  To make the standard deviation large you need to make the numbers as far apart as${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: ${}\ldots\,{}$possible.  For example, if you don't get $9$ in your sample, then changing to $9$ the number that is closest to $9$ will make the standard deviation bigger.  Similarly for $1$.  That means the sample that makes the standard deviation as large as possible contains $1$ and $9$.  But what about the third number?  There some trial-and-error might shed some light. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @baudolino : I wouldn't say "no variance" if the variance is $0$.  "No variance" is a term often used to describe situations like what happens with the Cauchy distribution, where the variance is infinite. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you very much @MichaelHardy

Comment: @MichaelHardy I know; my point was rather that if I'm allowed to choose the same things, there's no inherent randomness, no underlying r.v. to begin with and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a stab at that portion of the problem this not answered in comments under the question.  The three numbers are $1,x,9$.  The mean is
$$
\bar x = \frac {1+x+9} 3
$$
so the sum of squares of deviations from the mean is
\begin{align}
& (1-\bar x)^2 + (x- \bar x)^2 + (9-\bar x)^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \frac{ -7-x } 3 \right)^2 + \left( \frac {2x - 10} 3 \right)^2 + \left( \frac {17-x} 3 \right)^2 \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{ 6x^2 - 60 x + 438 } 9 = \frac {6(x-5)^2 + 288} 9.
\end{align}

This last expression is equal to $\dfrac{288} 9 = 32$ if $x=5$, but is bigger than that if $x\ne5$. (And $5$ is the average of $1$ and $9$.)